# Dynamically change icon size in leaflet

Tags: cordova, leaflet

Is there any way to dynamically change the iconSize of a marker in leaflet? I would like my app to let users change the size of the markers on a map by using a slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the size of an instance of `L.Icon`.

What you can do, however, is create a new instance of `L.Icon` with the desired size, and run `setIcon()` on a `L.Marker`.

Comment: is this still the case in 2019 ? No way to dynamically change icon size ? Thanks !